# Twilio webhooks - notify two different third party aplication

Tags: api, twilio, webhooks, notify

We are working on an integration between Twilio and a third party application. We have already an integration between Twilio and Zoho CRM, which means that Twilio notify Zoho CRM through webhooks when a call comes in/goes out. See the details on attached image.

[image]

Our question is the following:
Is it possible to setup a secondary wehbook which notifies the other third party application when a call comes in/goes out? And if this is possible how we can setup this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio develoepr evangelist here.

You can't setup two webhooks for one number. However what I would suggest is that you create your own server that receives the webhook from Twilio and then sends it on to each service individually. That way you can expand this to as many services that you need.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer.

Comment: No worries! If it helped, can you mark it as correct so that other people can see the solution.

Comment: this is a bummer

Comment: Why is that @dowi? It shouldn't be too hard to set up a service for yourself that can notify as many other services via webhook as you like.

Comment: @philnash can it be done with "functions"?
And I understand, it would just be easier setting just another line of text on Twilio :-)

Comment: You could definitely do this with Twilio Functions. I appreciate that it would be easier for you to just configure it, it's just not something we offer. For one thing, it would break our fallback logic. Currently, if your webhook doesn't respond with a successful status Twilio will send a webhook to a fallback URL. If there were multiple URLs how many would fail to cause a call to the fallback URL? The model is simpler in this case for most use cases, but it does leave you to create your own webhook forwarder.

Comment: @philnash OK got it (the fallback issue). will try it none the less. thanks!

Comment: Cool, let me know if you have any trouble.

Comment: @philnash is it possible to use your suggested approach to dial both services? I have a very similar use case to the OP. I want to dial both the Zoho CRM client (which has its own webhook) and my own Twilio client. The use case is that the Zoho CRM client only works on computers whereas my client works on mobile phones. I'd like to route it initially to my mobile app and if it doesn't answer after some time, forward it to zoho crm.

Comment: @jeznag I think that could work for you, possibly like this. You could set a timeout on `<Dial>` and then inspect the `DialCallStatus` in the webhook to the `action` parameter. If the status is "no-answer" then you could forward the request to the Zoho CRM.